# Support for remote reboot of Google Meet Hardware Device

Tags: google-workspace, google-meet

We are looking for a solution to programmatically reboot Google Meet Hardware devices (ASUS Chromebox) through an REST API. We can press the reboot-button in the Admin UI and we have tried the https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/customer.devices.chromeos.commands reboot command, but that seems only to work on regular ChromeOS devices, not Google Meet hardware devices.

Any known solutions for this?

Cheers
Olof

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Google Meet Hardware have their API, and if I remember correctly the policies for regular Chrome devices and Google Meet hardware are different, and they are managed in different places in the Admin console. You can add a feature request for Google Meet hardware in [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/support#missing_features)